# Cycles Bake - Noise texture becomes flat color

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

While trying to convert some textures from using generated textures (and generated texture coordinates) to UV image textures, I keep running into an issue where I lose a large amount of my textures' detail when baking.  Particularly, noise textures (which I use liberally) seem to be completely ignored by the baking process.  It happens regardless of whether I put Cycles in GPU or CPU mode.
[image: Upper-Right: the texture as visible, Left: the incorrectly baked texture]
How can I get the influence from the noise textures to be visible on the baked texture?

Edit: I've figured out that it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the bake itself - the noise texture node doesn't seem to be applied at all to the render preview in cycles.  Compare the texture preview in the above screenshot with the render preview below:
[image: the wood texture is a plain brown now]

Same image, same mode, this time using eevee:
[image: the wood texture is visible]

Comment: Note: I switched back into Eevee after writing this post and found that the material preview displays the noise detail in Eevee, but not in Cycles.  Probably related, but doesn't really help me find a solution.

Comment: hello, please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've uploaded it here: https://pasteall.org/blend/0142f9885b2f45af80924740ff1ca992
Not sure whether including the images will help, because there are no images besides the bake itself.  Also I think I've figured out that it doesn't actually have to do with the bake itself, since the noise textures just plain don't render in Cycles at all

Comment: Ok so I think you were unable to see the texture in Cycles (and therefore bake the Diffuse) because of the Texture Coordinate From Instancer option, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the *From Instancer* option of the *Texture Coordinate*, otherwise the texture won't appear in Cycles (and you won't be able to bake):

[image]